# How do I get a 3rd Gwent Decoy card?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I'm playing The Witcher 3 and I love to play Gwent. I'm currently in the process of getting all the Gwent cards. I know there are three Decoy cards which you can get at the following locations:

- Quartermaster’s, Baron’s Store, Crow’s Perch
- From a Trader at Seven Cats Inn
- From an Innkeeperess at White Orchard Tavern

I've bought the first two cards from the top two. However I went back to the Inkeeperess at the White Orchard Tavern, but she is not there anymore. I did some searching on the internet and they said the merchant next to the White Orchard Tavern would have it. I checked his store but he did not have a Decoy card. I have seen posts from other people who experiencing the same problem. Is there a workaround to get the third Decoy card? I'd really want it, but to throw away like 70 hours of gameplay for one (however very powerful) card seems a bit much.

Does anyone know any options I can try?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this video](https://youtu.be/Nw3aWSsH9O0?t=4m9s), the quartermaster at Crow's Perch offers the decoy multiple times if you missed it before, so that you are still able to get the card if you didn't buy it in the White Orchard tavern.

You need to buy the card from him, exit the trading menu and start trading again to make another decoy show up in his inventory.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the either Inkeep and buy a decoy off of them, meditate for 24 hours not 23 make sure it goes all the way round and but it again